# G is a finite group. N is normal in G and G/N is nilpotent

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a finite group. $N$ is normal in $G$ and $G/N$ is nilpotent. Prove that

1. There exists a subgroup $K$ in $G$ such that $K$ is nilpotent and $G=NK$
2. Suppose $N$ is abelian, $Z(G)=1$. Prove that $K\cap N={e}$ and $K=N_G(K)$

this is one problem in my exam and I've already solved 1.. By supposing $G$ is not nilpotent and use induction on $o(G)$.

I'm stuck with 2. since it seems irrelevant. Obviously we have to take $x\in N_G (K)$ and prove $x\in K$, but the hypothesis doesn't seem helpful to me. Help me with this. THank you

Comment: Just to make sure. In proving 1, have you used the Frattini subgroup? I believe it's sort of necessary.

Comment: Sure. Personally, it must be involved with Frattini argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of 2, suppose $L = K \cap N \ne \{e\}$.

**Hint 1**

> Then $L$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of the nilpotent group $K$, and thus $M = L \cap Z(K) \ne \{e\}$.

**Hint 2**

> Therefore $M$ centralizes $K$.

**Hint 3**

> But since $M \le L \le N$, and $N$ is abelian, $M$ centralizes also $N$, and then it is contained in the centre of $G$, a contradiction.

For the second part of 2, let $X = N \cap N_{G}(K)$

**Hint 4**

> $N_{G}(K) = X K$. This follows from the identity $A \cap B C = (A \cap B) C$ is $A \ge C$.

**Hint 5**

> $X$ centralizes $N$.

**Hint 6**

> $[X, K] \le N \cap K$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints. I'll try

Comment: I got the first part. I don't get your point in the second part. I mean What are you trying to prove?

Comment: Pardon my stupidicity. I got why you do this now

Comment: One more question. Why [X,K]< N

Comment: Because $N$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: My bad! I thought I deleted that comment. Thank you for your help